# Send requests to mfc views / Update views

Tags: mfc

I have a project with many mfc views.

how can I send many requests to update views in the same time in c++ (mfc) ?
how can I use CWinthred classes ?

Answer (score 2):

1. From your thread you should call `PostMessage(WM_NEED_TO_UPDATE_ALL_VIEWS)` to post your custom message (`WM_USER` based) to your main window.  (which is `CMainFrame` I assume)
2. When you receive `WM_NEED_TO_UPDATE_ALL_VIEWS` in your main app window you should call `UpdateAllViews(NULL);` method to update all views.

Comment: As `UpdateAllViews()` is a member of CDocument class, the App would have to iterate through all Documents to do that. Also, the thread function probably working on a data in one particular document, so it should have a pointer to that document and post message to it directly (it is derived from CCmdTarget after all).

Comment: I agree Vlad. But I guess I've described the basic approach that would give an idea on how to do that.